# How to configure Terser in Remix.run (2.5.0)?

Tags: remix.run, terser

I'm trying to set my Remix (2.5.0) app to use Terser but it seems that it is not working.

With the following configuration I was expecting not seeing console.logs but I still can see then and inspecting the source on the browser I can still see the console.log there.

Here is my remix.config file:

```
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
import terserOptions from './terser.config.js';

export default {
   ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
   server: "./server.ts",
   serverBuildPath: "functions/[[path]].js",
   serverConditions: ["workerd", "worker", "browser"],
   serverDependenciesToBundle: "all",
   serverMainFields: ["browser", "module", "main"],
   serverMinify: true,
   serverModuleFormat: "esm",
   serverPlatform: "neutral",
   optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({ terserOptions })],
   },
...
```

And here is my terser.config.js file:

```
export default {
   compress: {
     drop_console: true,
   },
   mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
 }
```